# GitHub API returned Url meaning

Tags: git, api, url, github, github-api

Take this very simple API as example,

https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui

In the JSON formatted response, you'll find something like following,

`"following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/following`**`{/other_user}`**`",`
`"gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/gists`**`{/gist_id}`**`",`
`"starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/starred`**`{/owner}{/repo}"`**`,`

Ok, I know like the `following_url`, `starred_url` is something like a sub API which you can call to fetch who that user are following, or what repos that user has starred.

But, what does those braces mean? The one I've made it **Bold**. How do I use them?

Comment: Have you actually looked for api documentation on github?  https://developer.github.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are placeholders value, that you would need to replace by an actual value in order to use those links.

It serves to remind a user how to access, for instance, the following_url for another user.

- without `{/other_user}`, that url https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/following would list all users followed.
- with `{/other_user}`, that url https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/following/xxx would check if you follow user `xxx`.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to replace that placeholder with a user that I'm following which results in a request as following, https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/following/torvalds, but it made no difference on the result as the one just returned by without /torvalds

Comment: @ScottZhu try it in another tab of your browser. Better yet, try it with `wget`. You will see that `wget https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/following/torvalds` returns http error 204 no content (you do follow torvalds). while `wget https://api.github.com/users/zhuhuihuihui/following/VonC` returns http error 404 Not found: you do not follow me. Wait... you do not follow me?

Comment: I got it! Thank you. BZW, I just followed you hahaha